# Find the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ e^{-ax^{2}}-e^{-bx^{2}} }{x}dx,\ a>0,\ b>0$

Tags: integration

Find the integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ e^{-ax^{2}}-e^{-bx^{2}} }{x}dx,$$
$a>0,\ b>0$.

I tried to split the integral and use Feynman substitution, but I got an answer that doesn't look like the right one.

I considered this integral $$\int_{0}^{∞}dy\int_{0}^{∞}e^{-ax^{2}-xy}dx.$$

Comment: Please shows us what you tried.

Comment: How should this converge near 0?

Answer (score 3):

This is a [Frullani integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral) with the choice $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$, but you have to be careful about choosing $a$ and $b$, because the "$a$" and "$b$" in your question are *not* the same as those in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ e^{-ax^{n}}-e^{-bx^{n}} }{x}dx=\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ e^{-at}-e^{-bt} }{t}dt$

Answer (score 3):

Let $J(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ e^{-tx ^{2}}-e^{-x^2}}{x}dx$. Then
$J’(t)= -\int_{0}^{\infty}x e^{-tx ^{2}}dx=-\frac1{2t}
$ and
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{ e^{-ax^{2}}-e^{-bx^{2}} }{x}dx
=J(a)-J(b)=\int_b^a J’(t)dt= \frac12\ln \frac ba
$$